# select2 values from php

Tags: php, jquery

I really stuck with select2 and the tags mode. I want to let the user enter data as tags. Seperated by " " and ",". No problem. I've got this.

Now I want to gather the already available tags by a php file. I've already tried several snippets from google and here. The php file returns a json_encode. Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
  if($('#s2_tag_handler_receipient').length) {
            $('#s2_tag_handler_receipient').select2({

        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
        createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {

            if ($(data).filter(function () {
                return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
            }).length === 0) {
                return {
                    id: term,
                    text: term
                };
            }
        },
        multiple: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "imapMailBox/autoCompleteReceipientsJson.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        }       
            });
        }
```

This is the php file:

```
<?php 
    $return[]=array('Paul','NotPaul');
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
<?php 
    $return=array('Paul','NotPaul');
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

This will give : `["Paul","NotPaul"]`

In your version it gave : `[["Paul","NotPaul"]]`

Comment: Hm, sorry no. I use FireBug and the return values are: ["Paul","NotPaul"] but I get an error TypeError: a is undefined
 

...0),e===d.length-1&&(j=c.find("li.select2-more-results"),j.length>0&&(g=j.offset(...